# Save input field text displays over bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a ASP.net MVC4 project where the bootstrap date pickers recently stopped working as intended in Chrome, they work fine in IE.

This image shows the issue I'm having.

[image: DatePicker]

My bundleconfig looks as follows:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"
                    )
                    );


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/createTimeRequest").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/createTimeRequest.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/moment.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Calendar").Include(
                                "~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js",
                  "~/Scripts/dataTables.jqueryui.js",
                  "~/Scripts/dataTables.foundation.js",
                  "~/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/dataTables.buttons.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                  "~/Scripts/buttons.print.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                   "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css",
                   "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.base.css",
                   "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css",
                   "~/Content/dataTables.bootstrap.css",
                   "~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css",
                   "~/Content/dataTables.foundation.css",
                   "~/Content/dataTables.jqueryui.css",
                   "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                   "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css",
                  // "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css",
                   "~/Content/fullcalendar.css",
                   "~/Content/site.css",
                   "~/Content/buttons.dataTables.min.css"
                  ));
```

The javascript file that tells the input field to be a datepicker via a class reference looks as follows:

```
var year = (new Date).getFullYear();
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        orientation: "right",
        startDate: new Date(year, 0, 1),
        //endDate: new Date(year, 11, 31)
    });

    $('.dpManager').datepicker({
        orientation: "right",
        endDate: '+365d'
    });

})
```

And the razor syntax in the view is as follows:

```
  <div class="col-md-4"><label>Select company: </label>@Html.ListBox("Company", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Company, new { @class = "form-control", size = 9 })</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.Label("Start Date:")
                @Html.Editor("sDateTime", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "dpManager form-control" } })

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.Label("End Date:")
                @Html.Editor("eDateTime", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "dpManager form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/createTimeRequest")
}
<script>
        if (!$("#sDateTime").val() || !$("#sDateTime").val()) {
            $('#btnSubmit').prop("disabled", true);
        }
</script>
```

This is my layout file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


</head>
<body>
   ........
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

This just happened this week, perhaps chrome rolled out a new update? You can see the datepicker is showing up but the saved input takes precedence for whatever reason. I tried updating my jquery & jquery ui. Only thing I didn't try yet was to update bootstrap. Not sure if I want to try that and break other things.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to use autocomplete=off

```
<input autocomplete=off />
```

[How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: Wow, I spent 2 hours on this. I searched everywhere but didn't use autocomplete in my searches. Duh, thanks so much.

Comment: Also you can submit your form with ajax.

Comment: Yeah I know, this is an old app I inherited.

Comment: Does it work ? don't forget to accept the answer ;) You can do : `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker().attr("autocomplete", "off")`

Comment: That's a clever idea, better then writing it out on each input field. Good thinking.